# Determine if an Exchange 2010 Management Role Assignment is Built-In

Tags: exchange-2010

How can I determine if a given Exchange 2010 management role assignment is built-in (i.e., installed with Exchange) or not?

The best I've come up with so far is going off the `WhenCreated` attribute, but that's hardly authoritative.

Comment: Compare them to the defaults? - http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/exchange-2010-role-based-access-control-part1.html

Comment: @joeqwerty, see my comment on the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tohuw,

You'll need to drill down on Technet here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638077%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx

Click on the particular role and then expand the "Default Management Role Assignments".

That will give you the defaults that are included in a particular role.

Comment: Thanks for the concise list; it saves some time. I was hoping to figure out an authoritative way via Shell to automate an auditing process, but it looks like I'll just have to build a list myself from what you linked. Cheers.

Comment: yeah, I don't recall it ever showing "built-in" vs. user-add in the GUI or the shell.

Comment: @TheCleaner correct. internally, there is no difference. think of them less as "built-in" and more as "defaults provided".